# Do we have to put all passed in arguments into its own self. variable before using them in another expression in the class?

Tags: python, class, variables, arguments, redundancy

In the following code:

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, screen: pygame.Surface, states: dict, start_state: str):
        self.done = False
        self.screen = screen
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.fps = 60
        self.states = states
        self.state_name = start_state
        self.state = self.states[self.state_name]
```

Why do we put the passed in arguments ***states*** and ***start_state*** into variables ***self.states*** and ***self.start_states*** before using them in creating the ***self.state*** variable?

Do we have to put all passed in arguments into its own self. variable before using them in another expression in the class?

Would it work if we did the following instead:

> self.state = states[state_name]

Comment: no it is not necessary. You can use argument from `__init__` directly inside the `__init__` function as in any other function but not reuse it later in a different method in the class in that case. So yeah if You ask whether it will work then yes it will work

Comment: e.g. `self.state = states[start_state]` as the first line of `__init__` would work and make no difference.